# Installing NVIDIA Drivers for Diskless Environment

Tags: centos7, nvidia

I'm trying to set up a cluster of 8 computers plus a main file server. Ideally, I'd like to set this up in a pxe-boot, quasi-diskless/quasi-stateless environment (i.e. the only local storage is `/var`, where things like torque configuration will go). Each of the 8 compute nodes has 4 NVIDIA Tesla K40m's, but the root file server has no GPU.

Ideally, I'd like to be able to create the complete installation on the file server (at `/node`) then PXE-boot that to the compute nodes, but, I haven't found a way to install the NVIDIA drivers without an NVIDIA GPU on board. I found [one question on NVIDIA's forums](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/509783/install-cuda-drivers-toolkit-and-sdk-for-stateless-nodes-in-a-cluster-nonstandard-install-how-to-c/) about how someone unsuccessfully attempted this...

Alternatively, I could install the NVIDIA drivers to one of the compute nodes (one is currently running CentOS on it's local disks) to (for example) `/usr/local/nvidia` and keep track of what files it creates and create a tarball of that to copy to the file server installation.

Lastly, I could just maintain eight separate installations, but, I don't like this from a long-term maintenance perspective (each compute node will be running torque jobs so I'd like the nodes to look more-or-less identical).

In summary, what I'm asking for is this:

1. Can I install the NVIDIA drivers without an NVIDIA GPU on board?
2. Is there some other way I should be going about this?

For reference, we're running CentOS 7.

```
[root@compute-3 /]# uname -a
Linux compute-3 3.10.0-514.2.2.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Dec 6 23:06:41 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use RPM packages, like everything else.

At the moment the best built [NVIDIA driver packages](http://negativo17.org/nvidia-driver/) are from Negativo17.

Comment: Ah, sometimes the easiest solution is the one you think of last.